# TypeError: string indices must be integers in ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, typeerror

I am following the EalsticSearch tutorial (https://soumilshah1995.blogspot.com/2020/01/getting-started-with-elastic-search-and.html) and I am running into the following error when trying to execute

```
es.indices.create(index='person', ignore=400)

res1 = es.index(index='person',doc_type='people', body=e1)
res2 = es.index(index='person',doc_type='people', body=e2)

print("RES1 : {}".format(res1))
print("RES2 : {}".format(res2))
```

I have downgraded my Elasticsearch down `elasticsearch==5.5.3` but still running into the same error.

Some help would be great

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded the Elasticsearch to the latest version and changed the formatting of the code to:

```
es.indices.create(index='person', ignore=400)

res1 = es.index(index="person", id=1, document=e1)
res2= es.index(index="person", id=1, document=e1)

print("RES1 : {}".format(res1))
print("RES2 : {}".format(res2))
```